# Run a GitHub action in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

For some projects with `R`, I have a `GitHub action` that creates a container for the application a specific operating system and a specific version of `R`.

I want to migrate this action from GitHub to workflow to manage everything in Azure DevOps. The migration doesn't see straightforward because I can't find a way to run the GitHub action in Azure DevOps. All the posts I found are quite old. Maybe Microsoft did something new to integrate the actions in DevOps (I hope).

The GitHub action is the following

```
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/master/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master, dev]

name: RCheck

jobs:
  RCheck:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      # We keep a matrix for convenience, but we would typically just run on one
      # single OS and R version, aligned with the target deployment environment
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: windows-latest, r: '3.6.3'}
          # - {os: windows-latest, r: 'latest'}

    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes

    steps:
      - name: Check out Github repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Pandoc
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - name: Install R
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}
          use-public-rspm: true

      - name: Install R Dependencies
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: |
            any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check

      - name: Check R Package
        uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
        with:
          args: 'c("--no-manual", "--as-cran", "--no-multiarch")'
          error-on: '"error"'
          check-dir: '"check"'
          upload-snapshots: true
```

Is there a way to import this action in Azure DevOps? Is there any extension for Azure DevOps I can use? Is there any documentation how to migrate action to Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

You can Run A Github Action in Azure Devops
Using following Commands

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az login
      az account set --subscription $(azureSubscription)
      az repos create --name my-repo
      az repos import create --git-url https://github.com/my-org/my-repo --repository my-repo
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $githubToken = "$(githubToken)"
      $repository = "$(githubRepository)"
      $branch = "$(githubBranch)"
      $command = "curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/$($repository)/actions/workflows/MyWorkflow.yml/dispatches -H 'Authorization: token $githubToken' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -d '{""ref"":""$($branch)""}'"
      Invoke-Expression -Command $command
```